# Look up and remove variables, based on factors

Tags: r

I wish to create a lookup list of patients who do not have a condition, tested at multiple dates. My lookup data.frame is over 32892 observations long but here is a small example

```
PatientName <- c("Alice", "Tom", "Dave", "Michele", "Wendy", "Alice", "Tom", "Wendy", "Alice", "Wendy")
SubjectiveCondition <- c("Dizziness", "Normal", "OK", "High Heart Rate", "Normal", "Good", "High Heart Rate", "Dizziness", "Normal", "High Heart Rate")
Date <- c("01/09/2017", "01/09/2017", "01/09/2017", "01/09/2017", "01/09/2017", "02/09/2017", "02/09/2017", "02/09/2017", "03/09/2017", "03/09/2017")

lookupdf <- data.frame(PatientName, SubjectiveCondition, Date)
```

I then have a study experimental data.frame which contains a physiological sample from each patient at each date. An example is:

```
PatientName <- c("Alice", "Tom", "Dave", "Michele", "Wendy", "Alice", "Tom", "Wendy", "Alice", "Wendy")
Sample <- c(120, 110, 120, 150, 210, 300, 290, 110, 150, 260)
Date <- c("01/09/2017", "01/09/2017", "01/09/2017", "01/09/2017", "01/09/2017", "02/09/2017", "02/09/2017", "02/09/2017", "03/09/2017", "03/09/2017")
experimentaldf <- data.frame(PatientName, Sample, Date)
```

I wish to lookup each patient at each date and if they have "Dizziness" or "High Heart Rate" then exclude them from the `experimentaldf`

My anticipated output of the revised `experimentaldf` would then be:

```
PatientName <- c("Tom", "Dave",  "Wendy", "Alice", "Alice")
Sample <- c(110, 120, 210, 300, 150)
Date <- c("01/09/2017", "01/09/2017", "01/09/2017", "02/09/2017",   "03/09/2017")
revisedexperimentaldf <- data.frame(PatientName, Sample, Date)
```

Is this please possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that every patient has an unique id (so no patients with the same name), you can left join experimentaldf on lookupdf by "PatientName" and "Date".

```
join_set = merge(lookupdf,experimentaldf,by=c("PatientName", "Date"),all.x = TRUE)
```

After that you can use subset() to select the group you need based on your conditions.

```
total_exp = subset(merged_set, SubjectiveCondition != "Dizziness" &  SubjectiveCondition !="High Heart Rate")
```